# migrate local profiles to UPD

Tags: migration, user-management, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services, user-profile

We have a farm of RDSH servers, that are currently using local profiles. I would like to migrate them to UPD, ( User profile disks). Not too sure on how to copy data from local profile of some 40 users to upd vhdx files before hand. As the UPD(s) only tend to get created upon initial logon of the user.